# Hosting EDUCATIONAL Phishing Site

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, firebase-hosting, phishing

Is there any place where I can legally host a phishing site for educational purposes? I need to for my Information Security course project. I've hosted it on Firebase and Github but they've both been taken down. Any hosting sites that will allow this?

Tried hosting on Firebase and Github, got removed and flagged

Comment: How would you expect your web hosting provider to know that your website is here for legitimate reasons and that it is not a real phishing website?

Comment: I mean fair enough but is there any hosting site that would allow it?